# Geometry extraction from trajectories

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I have some trajectories of people moving in a given geometry.
For example
[image]

In this example, the geometry was added manually, a process I would like to automatize: The question is then: **How to generate an approximation of the walls, shown as black lines in the picture above?**

### Code

Here is my Ansatz: count, in a grid, where people go (or not go), and hence identify the empty grid cells.
That would tell me where is inside and outside the geometry.
Assuming `Tx` and `Ty` hold the coordinates of all trajectory points:

```
from scipy import stats
dx = 0.1
xbins = np.arange(geominX, geomaxX + dx, dx)
ybins = np.arange(geominY, geomaxY + dx, dx)
ret = stats.binned_statistic_2d(
        Tx,
        Ty,
        None,
        "count",
        bins=[xbins, ybins]
    )
```

Plotting the counts per cell (`ret.statistic`) yields:

[image]

Now, from this, I calculated the points in the geometry with non-empty counts:

```
X = ret.x_edge + dx/2
Y = ret.y_edge + dx/2
x, y = np.meshgrid(X[:-1], Y[:-1])
xx = x[ret.statistic.T != 0]
yy = y[ret.statistic.T != 0]
plt.plot(xx, yy, ".")
```

which gives for `dx=0.1` the following result:

[image]

For the sake of explanation, I'd like to give another example of a bottleneck, where the boundaries of the geometry, the black lines, are added *manually*.

[image]
[image]

[image]

### Problem

This is now the point where I'm stuck and need some help.
Do you have any idea how I could proceed from here and automatically identify a rough approximation of the geometry's boundaries?

### Data

In case of trajectories are needed, here are two links to the above-used trajectories:

- [Crossing](https://fz-juelich.sciebo.de/s/gLfaofmZCNtf5Vx/download)
- [Bottlenck](https://fz-juelich.sciebo.de/s/HldXLySEfEDMdZo/download)

### EDIT (using OpenCV)

Thanks to @BlackBeans comment, I tried the following:

1. plot the trajectories with white on black background and save image:

```
# with a big marker size
ax.plot(d[:, 2], d[:, 3], "o", ms=10, color="white")
```

[image]

2. In the next step, read the image and find the contours:

```
img = cv2.imread("trajecotries.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, binary_img = cv2.threshold(img, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[1]
final_image = cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (178,34,34), 2)
```

[image]

That brings me closer to my goal.
However, the contours are not in original coordinates, but rather some numbers relative to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is usually called contour approximation. OpenCV has a function that does that for you, documented [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) (at the Contour Approximation  section). It is relatively straightforward to use.

Comment: Are you suggesting to plot the trajectories as an image and then running findContours on it? Did not work well for me.

Comment: I was thinking of running findContours on the image not of the trajectories, but just of the "presence" points (ie. a point is black if a trajectory passed by that point, otherwise white). Could you edit your question adding the result of this attempt, so I can understand why it didn't work out?

Comment: Now I get your points. It seems to work well, but with a minor issue: I need the contour to be in the original coordinates. Maybe I'm missing some minor detail.

Comment: To transform image coordinates to your previous coordinates, you can compute the pixel ratio (ie. by how much moving of a pixel in the images moves you in the original coordinate system) with the image size. If the part part of the plot you transformed into an image began at coordinates `(a, b)` (bottom left corner), ended at `(c, d)` (top right corner), and your image has dimensions `(width, height)`, and `(x, y)` are the coordinates of the image, then the new coordinates are `(a, b) + ((c-a)/width*x, (d-b)/height*y)`.

Comment: Thanks. You were a great help for me. 
Basically, this coordinates transformation works with a slight change. 
First, width and height are not from the image, but from `xrect, yrect, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)`.
Second, I had to center the points (x,y) as follows:  `Xc = a + (c - a) / w * (x - xrect)`.

Although this solves my problem, I'm not liking the fact, that I have to create an image to open it again and do some opencv magic, and then retransform everything back to the system coords. This does not feel straightforward, as I was hopping for another algorithmic solution.

Comment: @Tengis I understand why you don't like it. There is a partial solution: I don't think you need to save it as an image, then open it again. I think it's possible to just transform it to an image without saving it, but certainly not by plotting it (use a specific library like PIL instead). The second thing is that  you can think of black and white image just as a two dimensional array of booleans. It's just that OpenCV does not work on booleans, but on images. The last thing is that you could re-implement OpenCV's algorithm, but it's probably not worth it.

Comment: thanks again for the tip. I ended up using PIL as you suggested.

Comment: @Tengis just for information, in IA and in computer vision, it's not that rare to use images as a standard format, even for data that is not necessarily a picture originally, but was just an array. It's probably because images are a very flexible format (basically any of scalar values can be turned into an image without too much overhead), and because algorithms on images ended up working well on other things too. Long story short, it's kind of usual to convert data to images, you should not worry about it.